# Documentation - Is documentation available in a downloadable pdf format?

Tags: vhdl, documentation

Is documentation for Sigasi available in pdf document (so I can print it and cuddle up in a chair and read)?

Comment: Robert, if you use uncommon terms, explain them. Not everybody knows what Sigasi is (I don't)

Comment: @stevenvh: I guess if you don't know what Sigasi is, then you can't answer the question anyway.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - Then he should mention Sigasi already in the title. And I think it's polite to explain, even if I can't answer the question. "Hey, if you don't know what I'm talking about it's none of your business." doesn't sound nice to me.

Comment: @rocketmagnet: Sometimes an explanation helps, and may mean that you can help OP after all.

Comment: @stevenvh: Fair enough.

Comment: Nothing to do with Electronic Design. Question should be closed.

Comment: I think it's arrogant to expect us to know what "Sigasi" is.  For all I know, it has nothing to do with electronics so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

The manual is not available in PDF. Anyway, since it evolves constantly, it would be a waste of dead trees to print it. Would you be interested in an e-reader format? http://www.sigasi.com/content/creating-e-books-eclipse

Questions specific to Sigasi are welcome on the Sigasi support forum: http://www.sigasi.com/forums/support-forum. The Electronics StackExchange is probably not the best place to ask.

Comment: @Phillippe, have you moved the support forum? Or retired it in favour of something else?

Comment: You can find the manual at http://insights.sigasi.com/manual  You should also check http://insights.sigasi.com/ for more help and guidance.